# How to sort a large array of ints?

Tags: java, arrays

During job interview I was asked the following question:

We have a client application that can send a request and receive a data stream of ints (maybe large, but less than INT_MAX). We need to do this:

```
Int Data  ----> Our  ----> Sorted Int Data
Stream          App        Data Stream
```

So I would write the method as follows:

```
public int[] sort(int[] array){
   Arrays.sort(array);
   return array;
}
```

The problem is that the **large** `array` cannot fit into stack and will be put into **heap** which decrease performance. How to refactor it in a **good-performance way**?

Comment: If the data doesn't fit into the stack, I don't think there is any magic that will make it fit

Comment: @Felk Yes, that's why I ask how to approach it another way.

Comment: you'd have to come up with a logic to split the data up into chunks, then process the chunks somehow -> with heap sort or something

Comment: unless you can park the whole set of ints somewhere, I see no easy way of sorting the entire set. Even working in chunks will force you to check all the previous chunks.

Comment: @Lino they'd still end up having to sort the whole thing back together though, right? Although an initial paging could indeed improve the performance of the sorting itself.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to sort a stream of data? Streaming implies a continuous input of data. You can't sort a stream of ints until you have first downloaded all of the ints. So is your question simply "What's the fastest way to sort an array of ints"?

Comment: Have you looked at [parallelSort](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#parallelSort-int:A-)?

Comment: I only see a solution which requires you to write heavily customized methods. You could, for example, split everything into parts such that it fits, then sort every smaller snippet and later combine them sorted with a *zipper-like* approach. However you would need to avoid that the big result gets put their again, maybe keep it split with a custom class that looks like an `ArrayList` but internally manages several arrays. But I have no clue if the overhead in sorting justifies the avoidance of the heap.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Independent of the programming language, the usual way of sorting large amounts of data is the following:

- only sort a chunk of the data
- merge all the sorted chunks using merge sort.

Some optimized implementations even perform insertion sort or something alike on datasets that roughly fit into the CPU's cache (e.g. timsort).

However, since the data does fit into RAM, Java's native implementation should be already pretty much as fast as it gets. If it exceeds RAM, or you want to limit the RAM usage, you'll have to use [external sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting). But that is definetely slower, because it goes to disk

Comment: I have used external sorting to sort 60GB of data with this technique. The file was in .csv format and every line was containing two big decimal number. It wasn't so hard to implement. I divided this file as 64MB per chunk (temp. files). Then I sorted every chunk in itself. Rest was merge sort into the final file. It did work and was taking around 32 minutes in total. Adjusting the chunk size can also affect the time.

Answer (score -1):

Well....if they ask you to *how* to sort data and don't provide the data to be sorted, then Arrays.sort() should work fine. However, the best way to sort depends on the data, Quicksort and Insertion are the fastest for sorting Arrays of Integers, but for floating point arrays, you would need a specialized sort method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

^ That is a full list of many acceptable ways of sorting algorithms, with the mathematical downside to each.